# confusion in understanding scala's bound

Tags: scala, generics

I am reading [Demystifying Scala Type System](http://www.slideshare.net/dgalichet/demystifying-scala-type-system) , in the 17th slide there is a snippet:

```
class Test[+A] {
  def test[B >: A](b: B): String = b.toString
}
```

The slide says method test will accept type A or any super type of A. But seems I could pass any type to test.

```
vat t = new Test[Int]
t.test("foo")
t.test(List(1, 2, 3))
```

I have the same confusion when I read Programming in Scala .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important thing to remember here is that `Any` is a super type of any type, i.e.

```
Any >: A
```

In particular, assume

```
val t = new Test[Int]
```

This is, `A` is `Int`. Now we call

```
t.test("foo")
```

`"foo"` is of type `String`, but string is subtype of `Any`, and hence can be considered as such, therefore `test[B >: A](b : B)` can be called with `b` being `"foo"` and `B` being `Any`.

The following example should illustrate this, consider

```
class Test[+A](a : A) {
  def test[B >: A](b : B) : (A,B) = (a,b)
}
```

now, using

```
val t = new Test(3)
val x = t.test("foo")
```

we get

```
x: (Int, Any) = (3,foo)
```

Finally, to add some details, Scala will not always pick `Any`, but the least common supertype of `A` and `B`. This happens to be `Any` for `Int` and `String` (see http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/128 ), but may be something different for other examples, e.g., for

```
val s = new Test(Nil)
val y = s.test("foo")
val z = s.test(List(1))
```

we will get

```
y: (scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type, java.io.Serializable) = (List(),foo)
z: (scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type, List[Int]) = (List(),List(1))
```

Also note that the lower bound does not prevent passing subtypes of `A`

```
scala> val a = new Test(new AnyRef())
a: Test[java.lang.Object] = Test@6771a12

scala> a.test("foo")
res6: (java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) = (java.lang.Object@78b99f12,foo)
```

So, the question is, what are lower type bounds useful for? One possible answer is that they can be used for "controlling" the types of "output" positions, as typically used for covariant type parameters, see, e.g., http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/lower-type-bounds.html Roughly speaking, when appending an element to a (covariant) list of type `A`, you want to make sure that the resulting list is "at least" of type `A`. (I'm sorry for this being in parts hand-wavey, but as it goes beyond the scope of the original question, I just wanted to give a brief idea of why they are needed, for a full answer, it's probably better to create a new question)

Comment: In my example, if every type could be passed to test method, why we need a bound there ? And why it's an upper bound but not a lower bound ?

Comment: @user2018791 you cannot pass subtypes of A.

Comment: @user2018791 I added a brief explanation when lower bounds are useful, but maybe it's better to start a new question specifically asking this.

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu yes, you can pass subtypes of A, but they will be considered as being of type A, which is the least common supertype of A and any of its subtypes

Answer (score 0):

The parameter can accept any type because of Any. However, I dont think this example is very clear. If you put this snippet into worksheet

if defined the return type is something related to B, you will see the problems

```
class Test[+A] {
  def test[B >: A](b: B): B = b
}


class A

class B extends A

val test = new Test[B]

val t = test.test("test")
```

The return type is **not String**, is **Object**. so basically, it loses the type reference.

The reason we need to define like this is A is **covariant**. In this case, it can only be used in **return type** not **parameter** because of the definition of **Function1[-A, +B]**. If use def test(b: A)..... it will have compilation errors:

**covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type A of value b
  def test(b: A): String = b.toString**

Further, if you want to constrain the super type, you can have several options. one of it is using **implicit** to restrain the type.

```
class C

class CCC extends C

def test[B >: A](b: B)(implicit ev: B =:= C): B = b

val test = new Test[CCC]

test.test(new C)//ok

test.test("123")//compilation error
```